# CSS inheritance question, why do my <p> tags do what my <a> tags are doing?

Tags: html, css

I am a rookie CSS user, i have the following nav menu code and CSS to go along with it. The funny thing is that when i hover over the `<p>` element (You are viewing page xxx) in the nav menu, it changes colors as if it was an anchor tag, specifically hover.

I am very confused why it does this, I tried to be as specific as possible when selecting the anchor tags but it made no difference, I'm guessing it has something to do with inheritance but I'm not 100% sure. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening? Thanks

```
<?php 
// Generate the navigation menu
echo '<div id="navmenu">';
echo '  <p>';
echo '      <h3><a href="index.php">Compliance Report<a/> - <a href="nonreportinghubs.php">Non-Reporting Hubs<a/> - <a href="FastReportingHubs.php">Fast Reporting Hubs<a/> - ';
echo '      <a href="inactivehubs.php">Inactive Hubs<a/> - <a href="inactivebutreporting.php">Inactive But Reporting Hubs<a/><br />';
echo '      <a href="logins.php">Logins<a/> - <a href="customerlogins.php">Customer Logins<a/>  - <a href="checklogins.php">Check Logins<a/> - <a href="dbsize.php">Database Size<a/></h3>';
echo '  </p>';
echo '  <p> You are viewing <span class="page_title">' . $page_title . '</span></p>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

```
#navmenu {
border:                         2px solid gray;
text-align:                     center; 
}

#navmenu a:link {
color:                          black;
}

#navmenu a:visited {
color:                          black;
}

#navmenu a:hover {
color:                          gray;
}
```

Comment: You may want to look up the heredoc syntax for PHP.  Your system above is very hard to test w/o a browser.

Comment: I googled PHP heredoc and from the three pages I noticed it said "Heredoc is rarely used as the day by day usage is more complicated as creating strings with quotes or double quotes" on a few sites. I guess i can try it out and see how it goes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You close tags like: `</a>` not `<a/>`. `<a/>` will generate a new empty `<a>` and since you never close any of your `<a>`'s your whole `<p>` is basically the the `<a>` that is nested inside.

Comment: Almost certainly -- you should run your HTML through the W3C Validator to see what errors you have. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Also invalid <h3> inside <p> tag (not that this is causing the error), pick-one stick with it

Comment: I dont know how I missed that, i guess starring at something for a while i skip over the easy stuff. good catch.

Comment: @spudley I usually do, but since I have it broken out into separate PHP pages I cant validate the HTML on that page. Is there a PHP validation page? I didnt think there was one since it can be whatever you want it to be, thanks.

Comment: That was it, thanks for the help, i appreciate it. again, I am a rookie but that was a bad mistake on my part, I dont know how I missed that.

Comment: @Drewdin - validate the generated HTML, not the PHP code. open the page in the browser; view source; copy+paste entire source into w3c validator.

Comment: @Spudley, i gave gave you a 1 up, that suggestion has helped me 1000 times so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid.

You cannot have an `<h3>` element inside a `<p>` element. When you start the `<h3>` you end the paragraph (implicitly as end tags are optional for `<p>`). The browser then sees `</p>` as an error and silently discards it.

Get rid of the `<h3>`, whatever that data is, it isn't a sub-sub-heading anyway.

`<a/>` is nonsense as well. You probably mean `</a>`.

It looks like you would do well to learn to use http://validator.w3.org/ — it does a very quick and easy first pass QA for markup.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending your anchor tags with `<a/>` instead of `</a>`